# passing userData via ccmenuitem with ARC enabled

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting, kobold2d

I'm trying to pass an NSString via a menuitem using the following code

```
CCMenuItem * buyButton = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:buyLabel target:self selector:@selector(buyItem:)];
buyButton.userData = (__bridge void *)((NSString*)(itemName));
```

to the following selector

```
-(void) buyItem:(CCMenuItemLabel*)sender {
   NSString * itemName = (NSString *)sender.userData;
     }
```

but i'm crashing in the selector. I am using cocos2d with arc enabled, hence the bridge in the userdata assigment. (kobold2d). any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your actual crash problem is this:

```
NSString * itemName = (NSString *)sender.userData;
```

Look over it, what are you casting here? Right: you're casting `sender` to `NSString*` and then you're sending sender (the CCMenuItemLabel) a `userData` message. BAM!

Brackets to the rescue:

```
NSString * itemName = (__bridge NSString *)(sender.userData);
```

---

Also, why make it overly complicated when there's userObject?

```
buyButton.userObject = itemName;
```

userObject is an `id` type and requires no bridge casting, userData is `void*` and requires bridge casting

Comment: thanks steffen, i didn't try the proper cast you mentioned but userobject was the right move, worked great! looking fwd to seeing what you do with kobold kit!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its working

```
 CCMenuItem * buyButton = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:buyLabel target:self selector:@selector(buyItem:)];
 NSString *userDataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"kidnim"];            
 buyButton.userData = (__bridge void *)userDataString;

 CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:buyButton, nil];
 menu.position = ccp(240, 160);
 [self addChild:menu];
```

And buyItem function:

```
-(void) buyItem:(CCMenuItemLabel*)sender {
    NSString * itemName = (__bridge NSString*)sender.userData;
    printf("NSString: %s\n", [itemName UTF8String]);
}
```

And you will get Out put as

```
NSString:kidnim
```

Comment: Your code definitely worked, thanks but unfortunately I need to set the string. I'm missing something as to why your code works perfectly but changing the userdata definition to: 'buyButton.userData = (__bridge void *)((NSString *)([NSString stringWithFormat:@"kidnim"]));' doesn't

Comment: Unfortunately, the currently posted code isn't working for me

Comment: the code works when its on a layer alone, but below some other code that is otherwise functioning, it bails. the other code is loading info from a plist file and creating a CCScrollLayer. it seems removing a chunk that begins with this line makes it work: `  if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {
            plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"plist"];
            }` but i'm using the userobject answer thanks